# Detect office 365 (access) AND Visual C 64x using registry

Tags: ms-access, visual-c++, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a MS Access app which I am planning to sell to people however it uses ODBC (MYSQL) to connect to a backend MySQL DB plus obviously needs ms access (runtime at least).

I created an Inno Setup installer to check for installed components however I have come across some issues:

1. ODBC 64x fails unless you also have ODBC 32x installed
2. ODBC (either) cant install unless the respective bit Visual C++ 2015-2019 is installed
3. My registry path for Visual C+ detects the install but not the Bit version!
4. Ms Access 365 (2019?) isn't detected using my current registry detection methods.

Code used:

```
function GetHKLM: Integer;
begin
  if IsWin64 then
    Result := HKLM64
  else
    Result := HKLM32;

  Result := HKLM;
end;

function IsOfficeInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Office');
end;

function NormalAccessPath: String;
var
  Names: TArrayOfString;
  I: Integer;
  S: String;   
begin
  if not IsOfficeInstalled then
      Result:=''
  else
  begin
    if RegGetSubkeyNames(GetHKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Office', Names) then
    begin
      for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(Names)-1 do
        begin
          S := 'Software\Microsoft\Office\' + Names[I]+ '\' + 'Access';
          if RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, S) then
            Result:=S;
          S := '';
        end
    end    
  end;
end;

function IsNormalAccessInstalled: Boolean;
var
  Path: String;
begin
    Path:= NormalAccessPath;
    if Path <> '' then
      Result := True
    else
      Result := False
end;



function IsMySQLODBC51Installed: Boolean;
begin

  // the result was inverted in the original code; the original function returned
  // True if the ODBC driver was not installed, False otherwise, and according to
  // the function name it should be vice-versa
  Result := RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, 'Software\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver');
end;



function IsRuntimeAccessInstalled: Boolean;
begin

  Result := RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AccessRuntimeRetail - en-us');



end;

function IsVCInstalled: Boolean;
begin

  Result := RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, 'Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC');



end;

function AddAsTrusted: Boolean;
var
  Path: String;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Path:= NormalAccessPath;

    MsgBox('Adding Trusted Location', mbInformation, MB_OK);

    //Exec('C:\Me\freelance\Inno setup script\fixes.bat', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
    if Path <> '' then
      begin
        //if not RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, Path + '\Security') then
        //  RegWriteStringValue(GetHKLM, Path + '\Security','MedidropUseless', 'MedidropUseless')
        if not RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, Path + '\Security\Trusted Locations') then
          RegWriteStringValue(GetHKLM, Path + '\Security\Trusted Locations\Location1','Path', 'C:\MediDrop')  
      end;  

  Result := True;
end;
```

So for 2 & 3: 
I need to detect visualC's VERSION.
I tested the installer at a new location today and they already had visual C++ 2015 86x so my installed failed for ODBC 64x because visualC 64x was missing.  Obviously:

```
'Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC'
```

is not appropriate..

For 4:
As can be seen I am checking Software\Microsoft\Office however this computer did have  the 15.0 and 16.0 subfolders (terminology?) but did NOT have ACCESS in them so my installer thought it was not installed.

However.. it was, so I need to find a way of finding this 365 version of access!

Finally, at the end of the install I add a path for trusted location:

```
function AddAsTrusted: Boolean;
var
  Path: String;
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Path:= NormalAccessPath;

    MsgBox('Adding Trusted Location', mbInformation, MB_OK);

    //Exec('C:\Me\freelance\Inno setup script\fixes.bat', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
    if Path <> '' then
      begin
        if not RegKeyExists(GetHKLM, Path + '\Security\Trusted Locations') then
          RegWriteStringValue(GetHKLM, Path + '\Security\Trusted Locations\Location1','Path', 'C:\[MyAppName]')  
      end;  

  Result := True;
end;
```

Once again due to the 365 issue... this did not work.  I created the path correctly in 16.0 but since access wasnt there, I still needed to Enable Content when I opened the app the first time, something I don't want to do.

Does anyone know where I can start to figure the above issues out??

Comment: @MartynA I use the ODBC to connect to a cloud mysql database.  Is this not correct?

Comment: @MartynA sorry i will edit that.  Yes MS access frontend with Mysql backend